# Any suggestion for contact form rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in Rails , trying to make a contact form for my app, but I can not catch the parameters that comes from contact form (like name and message) in Emailer class without asscociating a model. Any suggestion on that? Here are the list of classes and controllers.
My Emailer class is :

```
class Contact < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "from@example.com"

# Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
# with the following lookup:
#   en.contact.send_email.subject
def send_email(contact)
@greeting = "Hi"

mail to: "ostadfree@gmail.com"
end
end
```

Staticpages controller is :

```
def email_contact()
  Contact.send_email().deliver
  redirect_to contact_url
end
```

Contact.html.erb is include a form and two buttons at the end:

```
 <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
 <%= link_to 'Send Email', email_contact_path %>
```

and send_email.text.erb is :

```
Contact#send_email

<%= @greeting %>, find me in app/views/app/views/contact/send_email.text.erb
<%#= "Name :" + @name.to_s %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your code, you really don't have a grasp on how rails is designed to work.  You're probably better off following a tutorial than getting a question like this answered here.

http://seanrucker.com/simple-ruby-on-rails-contact-form-using-activemodel-and-pony/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

in mailer:

```
def send_email(name,message)
  @greeting = "Hi"
  @name = name
  @message = message
  mail to: "ostadfree@gmail.com"
end
```

in controller:

```
def email_contact()
  Contact.send_email(params[:name],params[:message]).deliver
  redirect_to contact_url
end
```

where `name` and `message` - names of form's fields. If it sent a mails before, that code should work.

Anyway, check it, really: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot, though it still sends mail , but NO name and NO message.Anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: So you should check what `Params` hash contains in controller.